# CSS3 selector to select child of parent of parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Do something with this element</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<ul id="someId">
<li>This element:hover</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I wonder if it is possible to select the first li element of the first ul if I hover on the first li element of the second ul element.

I've tried selectors like:

```
#someId li:first-of-type:hover:parent:parent ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type
```

But it obviously doesn't work. I want to avoid using JavaScript and changing the HTML structure is not an option. Adding classes and IDs isn't a problem.

Is this selector possible with CSS3?

Comment: No. there is no CSS that will let you traverse UP the DOM

Comment: what about `someId:nth-child(1)`

Comment: @Scott...he want's to affect the menu **above** the `someId` menu..ain't gonna happen with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without JS you can't change dom elements. At first give id or class to ul, after it use jquery .hover () function. And use first-child element for getting li of ul.